# Minimize $\sum_i||Y_i-AX_i||^2$

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression, linear-models

I have N data vectors $X_i$ and N target vectors $Y_i$ where $i$ indexes the sample.
I would like to learn a linear map $A$ between the data and the target i.e find the matrix $A$ that minimize
$$\sum_i^N||Y_i-AX_i||^2.$$
Is that a well know machine learning problem ?
What would be the equivalent model in scikit-learn ?
I thought this is a linear regression, but in scikit-learn the documentation of the linear regression states

> LinearRegression fits a linear model with coefficients w = (w1, …, wp)
> to minimize the residual sum of squares between the observed targets
> in the dataset, and the targets predicted by the linear approximation.

So it seems like scikit-learn's linear regression learns a list of coefficients w = (w1, …, wp), not a matrix A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal linear regression where the target variable has multiple components. This is often referred to as "multivariate linear regression". To implement it with scikit-learn, you can use a normal `LinearRegression` model.

Given that you have no intercept term, you should use `fit_intercept=False`.

After fitting the model, you can find $A$ in the `coef_` attribute of the model:

> **coef_: array of shape (n_features, ) or (n_targets, n_features)**
>
> Estimated coefficients for the linear regression problem. If multiple targets are passed during the fit (y 2D), this is a 2D array of shape (n_targets, n_features), while if only one target is passed, this is a 1D array of length n_features.